# Debounce event with multiple inputs that share the same event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, debouncing

I am applying a debounce event to multiple inputs. How do I only debounce the change that come from the same input. For example, I have two input html render through a loop. The only available identifiers are `data-id` which come from Database.

```
<input data-id="1" />
<input data-id="2" />
```

Where `data-id` is something that is dynamically, and are rendered with a loop. So I attached ajax to the input keyup, and would like to debounce them so it does not fire thousands of times while user type. Here are my javascript:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '[data-id]', _.debounce(function () {
    // Ajax here
    $.post('/some_url', { some_data })
}, 1000);
```

Now this seems to work and it does debounce. But the problem is the debouncing event doesn't differentiate between two inputs. So if I change the first input and immediately start changing the second input, as long as I go fast enough, the keyup event on the first input won't fire.

I wonder how do I differentiate the debounce on each `<input>` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the inputs with `each` so you can call `_.debounce` for each of them:

```
$('[data-id]').each(function() {
  $(this).on('keyup', _.debounce(function () {
    // ...
```